# Conditional adding object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

```
axios.post('saveUser', {id, name})
```

If `name` is empty how could I exclude it in the param? if I put `({id, name})`, isn't the method would still have a property of name undefined?

I don't want this

```
const obj = {id: 123, name: undefined}
```

I want this `const obj = {id: 123}`

but I don't want to create a temporary variable like so

```
let obj = { id: id }; if(name) obj = { ...obj, name };
```

Comment: "*I don't to create temporary variable like so*" why? What's the problem with that?

Comment: @VLAZ I want to avoid mutable object, avoid `let` if possible

Comment: `let` is unrelated to mutable objects. It's for a mutable *variable*. You can do `const obj = {id}; if (name) obj[name] = name;` and the variable is immutable. The object isn't. Besides it is a very strange requirement. You *can* determine whether to have a property or not at creation time but it's usually not worth doing that. If you're creating the object right now, it doesn't really matter whether you're treating it mutably or not - assuming you're doing this in a function, it's still a pure operation.

Comment: If your server is not able to handle unpredictable data in `id` or `name` you have other problems than a superfluous property.

Comment: ok I just don't want temporary variable and see if there's a better way to handle this case.

Comment: `obj = name ? {id, name} : {id};` Not funky looking ES6 code that does useless spreading of empty stuff but...a single line that is clear. I'm not a fan of the conditional operator but it's OK in this case. More realistically, I'd just refactor the creation into a function have `obj = makeUser(id, name)` then not even worry what happens in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you adding object properties conditionally with ES6 syntax like this.

```js
const normalizeData = ({id, name = ""}) => {
  const condition = !!name; // Equivalent to: name !== undefined && name !== "";
  return {id, ...(condition && { name })};
} 
console.log(normalizeData({id: 123, name: ""}));
console.log(normalizeData({id: 123, name: undefined}));
console.log(normalizeData({id: 123, name: "Phong_Nguyen"}));
```

**Explain:**

- Using [`Default function parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) at line code `name = ""` to avoid `undefined` of name propety having not included in input object.
- Using [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) at line code `...(condition && { name })`

Comment: Could you change the first case so that it states an undefined name: console.log(normalizeData({id: 123, name: undefined}));?

Comment: I've just updated, Pls take a look at it @chrwahl  Pls let me know if it works.

Comment: That was exactly it @Nguyễn-Văn-Phong

Comment: nice. the answer is actually at this line `{id, ...(name && { name })};` correct? there's typo of double `;` at the end.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. It works like a charm ^^! @alice_morgan

Comment: `"there's typo of double ; at the end."` Oh yeah, Updated. Thanks @alice_morgan

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong this is genius! it's way better than creating a temp variable!

Comment: Yes. I'm glad to help you. Happ coding @alice_morgan

Answer (score 1):

You can create the object with the id first and then add a name afterwards:

```
const obj = {id: 123};
if(name) obj.name = name;
axios.post('saveUser', obj);
```